# Fast averaging over Pandas dataframe subsets

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to loop over a large number of trials and compute a weighted average for a number of subsets. Currently the data is in the long format with columns trial, area score.

```
  trial  area       score
0  T106     0     0.0035435
1  T106     1     0.0015967
2  T106     4     0.0003191
3  T106     4     0.1272919
4  T288     0     0.1272883
```

I have about 120,000 trials, with 4 areas and maybe 10 to 100 scores per trial, for a total of ~7million rows. My first thought was to loop over all trials within a loop over the 4 areas, build a temp dataframe to compute the scores, and adding scores to an external dataframe:

```
for area in range(4):
    for trial in trial_names.iloc[:,0]:  
        Tscore = 0
        temp_trial = pd.DataFrame(trials_long.loc[(trials_long['tname'] == trial) & (trials_long['area'] == int(area))])
        #match score in tria
        temp_trial = temp_trial.merge(scores_df, how='left')
        #sum score for all matching 'trial' +'area'                      #this will be weigted avrg, with >0.5 *2 and >0.9* 3
        temp_trial.loc[temp_trial['score'] > 0.9, ['score']] *= 3        #weight 3x for  >0.9
        temp_trial.loc[temp_trial['score'] > 0.5, ['score']] *= 2        #weight 2x for >0.5
        Tscore = temp_trial['score'].sum() / int(len(temp_trial.index))
        trial_names.loc[trial,area] = Tscore                    #store Tscore somewhere
        Tscore = 0    
print('done')
```

This solution takes upwards of 10mins on one 4.0 ghz thread. Time is really of the essence in this case and the computations need to happen in under 15 seconds or so. In R I'd normally use a number of vectorized functions to skip the loops, and any loops I did have would be paralleled over multiple cores, but in python I'm not familair with the best approaches. I would also be open to learning something new, perhaps hash maps?

Thanks!

Comment: at first glance I feel you can just use a pandas `groupby` over both area and trial, then `apply` a custom function to each subset to check your thresholds/calculate the weighted average. that'll save you at least one of those for loops, but probably both if you can vectorize the code within the function

Comment: Maybe replace multiple `df.loc` with a udf in a single run using `df.apply` will help. `groupby` both columns is also a nice catch!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what i tried:

```
df['weighted'] = df['score']
df.loc[df['score']>.9, 'weighted'] *= 3        
df.loc[df['score']>.5, 'weighted'] *= 2

# s is indexed by ('trial', 'area')
s = df.groupby(['trial', 'area']).weighted.mean()
```

took 1.16 seconds to process 7 million rows on a 6600k.

Comment: This is an elegant and effective solution. Thank you!